# createAlias/createCriteria hibernate INNER_JOIN

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am having two tables Parent and Child. The query I want to use in Hibernate Criteria

```
SELECT tcr.*
  FROM case_reminders tcr
 INNER JOIN case_reminder_opr tco ON tcr.case_id = tco.case_id
 WHERE tcr.case_status = 'OPN'
   AND tco.operator_id = 111;
```

I have written the criteria as

```
    Criteria ctr = getSession().createCriteria(CaseReminderOpr.class).add(Restrictions.eq("pk.oprOperatorId", operatorId));
    ctr.createCriteria("pk.crmCaseId", "CR", Criteria.INNER_JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("CR.caseStatus", STATUS.OPEN.getValue()));
    List<CaseReminderOpr> oprList = ctr.list();
```

tried with createAlias as well but I am getting error as

**ORA-00904: "CR1_"."CASE_STATUS": invalid identifier**

Classes of CaseReminders(Parent) and CaseReminderOpr(Child) as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CASE_REMINDERS")
public class CaseReminders implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CASE_ID")
    private Long caseId;

    @Column(name = "CASE_STATUS")
    private String caseStatus;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="CASE_REMINDER_OPR")
public class CaseReminderOpr implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private CaseReminderOprPK pk;
}

@Embeddable
public class CaseReminderOprPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CASE_ID")
    private CaseReminders crmCaseId;

    @Column(name="OPERATOR_ID")
    private Long operatorId;
}
```

Please help me with the inner_join query, appreciate your help again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change would be as below then it works. I have realized this later.

Make the Joincolumn as **insertable=false,updatable=false** in main entity class.

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name="CASE_REMINDER_OPR")
    public class CaseReminderOpr implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EmbeddedId
        private CaseReminderOprPK pk;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "CASE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private CaseReminders caseRem;
    }
```

Now the query should work as expected.

```
Criteria ctr = getSession().createCriteria(CaseReminderOpr.class, "CRO").add(Restrictions.eq("pk.oprOperatorId", operatorId));
    ctr.createCriteria("CRO.caseRem", "CR", Criteria.INNER_JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("CR.caseStatus", STATUS.OPEN.getValue()));
    List<CaseReminderOpr> oprList = ctr.list();
```

Hopefully I am clear in explaining.